# Is there exist /sbin/lilo in rhel 4?

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, rhel

Actually I am just trying to build up a cluster(beowulf) in which there is a modification required in /sbin/lilo for reflecting the access to master node by slave node after it goes up . I changed the /etc/lilo.conf.anaconda file for timeout=1200 , but unable to find the  /sbin/lilo file to get result of added linux.Please help me that where do i verify that the modificaion is been implemented??....I am working on RHEL 4.

Answer (score 2):

`lilo` was the boot loader of Linux a long time ago.

As far as I can tell, all distributions have moved to using `grub` as default instead, as it is much more robust. With `lilo`, the risk of ending up with a non-booting system were much higher.

It seems you are following an extremely outdated manual?

Comment: You are absolutely right sir, but I am talking about file(/etc/lilo.conf) which does exist in RHEL-9 version and some other distributions. Even RHEL-4 also use grub.My ques was,where I can found the file that can invoke the changes made in the lilo.conf.anaconda..??

Comment: If you do not use `lilo`, there is absolutely no point in modifying `lilo.conf`, because nobody will read that file. No process will read `lilo.conf.anaconda` either; that apparently is a template file used by the redhat installer. It's an example file for the admin, if he wanted to switch to lilo I believe (I don't use redhat).